# Install "outdated" app from Google Play

Tags: google-play-store

I want to buy Minit, but it says "This app isn't available for your device because it was made for an older version of Android." How can I install it?

This question was asked before ([How to install an app that is available on older and newer Android versions but not on mine?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252217/how-to-install-an-app-that-is-available-on-older-and-newer-android-versions-but)), but the only answer was download an APK, but 1, I can't find the APK anywhere cause it's a paid app, and 2, I'm not really comfortable pirating it because those sites seem really sketchy.

I've tried buying it on the Google Play website, but it requires a device it says is capable of running it before I can buy it.

Also it was last updated in late 2019 so I should still be able to run it.

I've also tried Aurora Store, but it doesn't show up when I search for it, and when I manage to get to the page for the app, it says "Download Failed App not purchased"

Sidenote: Why can't I comment on the old post? Apparently I need reputation? Wouldn't that be better than posting a new question?

Comment: Maybe I could use an Android emulator to trick it into thinking I have an older device? But I can't get any Android emulators working on Linux. Everyone seems to have abandoned Anbox in favor of Waydroid, and I can't get Waydroid to work on X11

Comment: Google forces app authors to update their apps and makes older apps unavailable for new devices. But of course the app can simply be incompatible with your device. BTW: It would be easier to help you if you would add a link to the app you are trying to buy. The more concrete a question is the higher the chance for an answer that directly helps you.

Comment: Why don't you mail the developer? Explain your problem to find out why it is incompatible and how to get it Working while legitimately paying //yes, commenting needs reputation but in this case it would not have helped because your problem is different to that of the linked one and you did the right thing by asking a new question. Upvoting to help you build up reputation.. Welcome to Android SE

Comment: Sorry here's the link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devolverdigital.minit You can find it if you search minit google play

Comment: @beeshyams The developer isn't updating the app anymore, so I don't think emailing them will help. Also I'm pretty sure it's not actually incompatible, Google Play just won't let me buy it 

"Starting from 1 Nov 2022, apps that don't target an API level within two years of the latest Android release (API 29 and below) won't be available to new users with devices running Android versions newer than your app's target API level. This means that new users won't be able to discover or install your app on Google Play"

Comment: Try using Aurora Store to spoof an Android 8 device. Right now the Play Store website displays my Pixel XL as compatible.

Comment: @jkmartindale Nah, Aurora Store doesn't let you buy paid apps